# Is it idiomatic to update a property of a prop, without an event?

Tags: vue.js

I pass the list of inputs as a prop,

```
v-for input in inputProps

    v-model input.value
```

Should I be using events, instead of v-model?

Passing an event to manually update a property of a value in a list would involve

`[index]'path to property'`, would it not?

Comment: You're not going to get a good answer to this question. Some will advocate only using events to update props. Some will push for state management. Some are fine with updating properties of objects or values in arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is idiomatic for [props to flow down and events to flow up](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow).

> when the parent property updates, it will flow down to the child, but
> not the other way around. This prevents child components from
> accidentally mutating the parent’s state, which can make your app’s
> data flow harder to reason about.

In the case of the `v-for`, yes, you would need to indicate the index of the item so the parent could take appropriate action on it. Depending on what you're doing, exactly, you might also [catch the native `input` event in the parent](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) and process it there, so that the child component is not involved in the transaction.